# How to read an entire log file after a given token into Logstash as one message?

Tags: regex, logstash, multiline

I have some log files that are new-line delimited. In order to grok them successfully, I'm trying to merge everything into one message by using the multiline codec:

```
codec => multiline {
      pattern => "/.*./g"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"        
    }
```

This works successfully but in the case where the log files are very long, I receive a "max lines reached" warning along with a _grokparsefailure.

The log files all end with a similar format, which is not too long, and this is the part I am interested in. The end of the log file starts with a series of asterisks, e.g:

```
********
start of end of log file
some more interesting logs
end of log file
```

How can I tell logstash to grab everything from the asterisks onwards as one message, and drop the rest?

Comment: Is the number of targeted lines constant? Does it have a reliable maximum? Do asterisks appear inside? Or before the targeted asterisk line? For those who do not know logstash, which regex flavor is that? Can you solve your problem if somebody helps you find a suitable regex? Can you use additional tools, e.g. sed to only print from asterisk line to the end?

Comment: Yes the number of lines is constant, and has a reliable maximum. Asterisks may appear inside and before but always less than the 8 in a row I have shown. I'm afraid I cannot use additional tools outside of logstash, and I do not know the flavour of regex. I believe I need additional help with the logstash configuration, not just finding a regex. Thanks

Comment: Good info; and it means that this is no answer. Just a little help: A regex to describe an actual line consisting only of 8 asterisks would be `^\*{8}$`. If the "line" is within one big string, which contains newlines, it would be `\n\*{8}\n`. Depending on regex flavor you might need to double-escape, i.e. use "\\" instead of "\". Otherwise these simple regexes should be flavor-independent. Looking at your code/config, it looks like the regex belong between the `"/` and the `/g"`. But the g should be discussed. Maybe a logstash guru can build on this. Good luck.